# change a class:hover background-color with js

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have read quite a few articles but still couldn't figure out.  Tried lots of methods they provided but still no luck.

I have this in my html

```
<a href="report.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Button 1</a>
```

this is what happens to css when hovered

```css
.btn-success:hover, 
.dropdown-toggle.btn-success {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I want to change the background color to blue using js.

Comment: Why with js if I might ask?

Comment: Your question is a bit odd, there's no sense to use JS for something CSS does out of the box. We should use JS only when i.e: a hover event triggers a change over an element in the DOM unreachable by standard CSS selectors (since CSS can only target child elements and next sibling). Also you shared with us a CSS class selector that says: `.dropdown-toggle.btn-success` which is not present in your HTML cause expects a single element with both classes which you don't have. probably you're missing a space: `.dropdown-toggle .btn-success`? Not sure again since your Q is a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd need to do this with js when you could just change it in your CSS. But if you must you could just add a class to the element using

```
$('.btn-success').addClass('hoverClass');
```

And in your CSS

```
.hoverClass:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing the class assignment.

First give the link an ID so we can isolate it within the dom.

```
<a href="report.html" id="myButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Button 1</a>
```

To change the appearance of that link you could change the class to btn btn-primary btn-lg", the default value for 'btn-primary' is blue.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").className = "btn btn-primary btn-lg";
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know why you turn to js as css is the best choice for what you need. I guess you might find the css for the link is somehow "tricky": it needs to written in the order of "lvha", i.e. a:link, a:visited, a:hover and a:active

Answer (score -2):

There are two Javascript events you need, the «onmouseover», that is triggered when the mouse move over the link, and the «onmouseout», that is triggered when the mouse moves aways from the link. I wrote a short example to you.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function hoverIn ( element )
                    {
                            element.style.background = "blue";
                    }

                    function hoverOut ( element )
                    {
                            element.style.background = "none";
                    }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="report.html" onmouseover="hoverIn ( this );" onmouseout="hoverOut ( this );">Click Me</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: There's no sense to use JS when we're supposed to use CSS `:hover`. Also it would be a good idea to leave inline JS out of templates. `addEventListerer` is here waiting to be used.

Comment: Ofcourse it does not makes any sense to use JS in such case. But the thread starter asked how it was done in JS, and i showed him.

Comment: Also, `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` are far better and bulletproof listeners for such cases, and as I've said, using `addEventListener` you could do like: `elements.addEventListener("mouseenter", someFn)` etc